# Program to securely log onto and pull data from web server HTML

Tags: php, python, mysql, security

I am hoping to build a program to securely pull data from a variety of external servers and then put this information into a standardized database (probably MySQL).  I know this is a very general description of a program, but I'm trying to build it in a few different cases.

***Example)*** My school uses two different web services (and sometimes professors built their own sites) to list homework for students.  I would like my program to log into each site and pull the assignment, due date, etc and put it into one database so that all homework can be displayed on one page, added to a calendar, etc.

**First question)** How do I do this in a secure way.  Some of the sites require me to log on with a pretty vital username/password pair.  Some cites even require a different username/password pairs. How would I log on to the site without listing my password somewhere in the source code (obviously this would be a bad design choice).  The sites do not provide an API to do this.  Say I need to draw from sites using 20-30 username/password combos.  Would the best way to do this then be to have a list of all my username password combos encrypted with a general password?

Comment: Check out the `requests` and `scrapy` modules for Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scrapy`, already mentioned in a comment, is a good first hint for further investigation into scraping with `python`. Personally, I prefer programming directly with `pycurl` and `BeautifulSoup`, but this is a matter of taste.

Regarding authorization, you should investigate whether the web sites you are about to scrape support `Basic` authentication. If so, you can easily pass user/password in a header (which is simple in `pycurl` which is why I love it). If `Form based` logins are required, the authentification will call for a bit more coding. Pray that no one insists on certificates... In any case, you should carefully make sure to use `https` and not `http` to avoid sending your password freely readable through the internet.